# How can I add GNOME extensions to both sides of the clock?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

In GNOME shell at the top bar all your extensions are placed between the clock and the top side hand side were the battery percent and wifi controls are.

So I was wondering if there was anyway to add extension to the left hand side between the '*Activities*' button and the clock? I need this because I just have to many extensions clogging the top bar up.

Comment: If you really have that many GNOME extensions, you need to trim back. That's nuts. I can **guarantee** that some of them are generating syslog errors, or causing intermittant system freezes/problems. Check with `grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: no I just have an 11 inch laptop and some of the extensions give me thermals, fan rpm, and cpu frequency

Comment: Did you check the grep command that I left you? If you like, edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: ya but my problem is lack of space in between the clock and wifi status

Comment: It would be helpful if you [edit] your question and add the complete list of specific extensions that are putting indicators in your top bar.If I'm not mistaken, there is no easy global way to move the indicators, but some specific extension may provide an option

Comment: I don't see that you've done the two commands that I left for you.

Answer (score 1):

You might check the `Frippery Move Clock` GNOME extension [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2/move-clock/). This will move the clock to the right side of the top panel, making room for your other extension icons.

Comment: if I can get it so the clock was still in the center but the extension extended that would be ideal.

Comment: @BudgetTech try this, and see if you like it :-)

Comment: it did not work because the clock is no not showing the time

Comment: @BudgetTech  Restart GNOME shell and see if it shows time. ALT-F2, then "r". It **may** be conflicting with one of your other extensions.

Comment: no that  wont work because it just dose not have the space

Comment: @BudgetTech did you restart GNOME shell? Are there any FMC prefs that need to be set? Temporarily disable ALL other extensions and enable FMC by itself and see if it works.

Comment: the problem is the space and thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: @BudgetTech It's unclear if you ever got FMC to work. If not, did you temporarily disable your other extensions as I suggested?

Comment: @BudgetTech status please